# why the req.session is undefined?

Tags: node.js

I am developing this webpage and after halfway through I realized I was not prepared for logout. So, I added a session watching tutorials, but it is not working. it only keeps on saying " TypeError: Cannot set property 'email' of undefined". I followed every steps in tutorials and checked lot of questions in stack overflow but none of them are helping at all.

Here is my chunk of code:

```
router.get('/login', function(req, res)
{
    userId = req.query.starId;
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM student WHERE starId = ?', 
[req.query.starId], (err, rows, fields) =>
{
    if(err)
    {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else{
        var result;
        var hashed;

        bcrypt.compare(req.query.pass, rows[0].password, function(err, match)
        {
            if (err) throw err;
            else
            {
                req.session.email = req.query.starId;     
                console.log(req.query.starId);
                if(match)
                {

                    res.redirect('/list');

                }
                else
                {
                    res.redirect('/home/');
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

});

I have required 'express-session' and

```
app.use(session({
    secret: 'Haha,youcannotguessit',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is the `app.use(session(...))` line before `app.use(router)`?

Comment: no its not. it is in top of the page

Comment: try changin this `router.get` to `router.post`

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar Yeah, it should be post. problem with post was, after user hit submit button it does not get the route and gives me error like Cannot GET /login

Comment: add another `GET` resource, `router.get`, here just render, maybe, a login form, (or infering from your code, just redirect)